# Sending System Out And Err To SLF4J not working when deploying to Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, cxf, logback, slf4j

I have an application working with :

- Apache CXF
- Tomcat
- SLF4J with logback implementation

The application is using an external Jar that prints to System Out and Err. I used sysout-over-slf4j to redirect the messages from the printstreams to the logback log file.
When I test this using a main class everything works fine and the printStreams are redirected to logback log file but when I start the application using Tomcat, only the print streams triggered from the classes of the application are redirected to logback while print Streams from the external Jar are printed to console and ignored by SLF4J.

I got an error on application start when using Tomcat that maybe the source of the problem but I'm not sure :

> 2017-04-23 23:11:53,511 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG - uk.org.lidalia.sysoutslf4j.context.SysOutOverSLF4JInitialiser.initialise()
>   {dim. avr. 23 23:11:53 CEST 2017} : Your logging framework class
>   ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger should not need access to the standard
>   println methods on the console, so you should not need to register a
>   logging system package. [SysOutOverSLF4JInitialiser.java:56]
>
> 2017-04-23 23:11:53,537 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG -
>   uk.org.lidalia.sysoutslf4j.context.SysOutOverSLF4J.getConfiguratorClassFromSystemClassLoader()
>   {dim. avr. 23 23:11:53 CEST 2017} : failed to load [class
>   uk.org.lidalia.sysoutslf4j.system.PrintStreamCoordinatorImpl] from
>   system class loader due to java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   uk.org.lidalia.sysoutslf4j.system.PrintStreamCoordinatorImpl
>   [PrintStreamCoordinatorFactory.java:83]
>
> 2017-04-23 23:11:53,537 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN -
>   uk.org.lidalia.sysoutslf4j.context.SysOutOverSLF4J.reportFailureToAvoidClassLoaderLeak()
>   {dim. avr. 23 23:11:53 CEST 2017} : Unfortunately it is not possible
>   to set up Sysout over SLF4J on this system without introducing a class
>   loader memory leak.

When I use the main class to test that print streams from the jar are redirected to SLF4J I don't get this error and the messages are successfully redirected to SLF4J.

Can someone please tell me if the errors I get are the source of the problem and in this case how to solve them.

If you need more information about source code or configuration please tell me.

Thank you,
REGARDS

Comment: similar issue, though not the same for us here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56975903